# formula to work out highest rated taking into account number of votes

Tags: algorithm

I need to display a list of things in order of their rating. The things can be rated from 0 to 5 stars. I'm sure I have seen a formula somewhere that works out which order they should go in.

For example, I think if one of the things has only had 1 review that is 5 star, I don't think they would appear higher than something that had 10 reviews with an average of 4.5 stars, if you see what I mean.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about or what the formula is?

Comment: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: We're likely going to need at least some more specific details. Are you looking for a SQL query? and http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: The user is often given a choice of order by most ratings, highest rating, most recent ranting _[sic]_, ... .

Comment: What intrigues me the most is: what language are you REALLY gonna use to "display a list of things in order of their rating"??? All of those in the tags? Really? As you posted no code in your question, one can remove all the tags as they are misleading...

Answer (score 2):

You should go thru following link to understand the formula which IMDB uses...

[IMDB ranking system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Movie_Database#Ranking_.28IMDb_Top_250.29)

Comment: Wasn't me, but probably because your link didn't work when you posted it.

Comment: Or because it's a link only answer.  You might want to quote the important bit of the link (i.e. the formula itself).

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into consideration who is the voter too - there are people that tend to give high stars, and others that not. So it won't be accurate to look only on the items and their votes. Thus, you better take into consideration two things:
The items, and the voters.

You better read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) how recommender systems work.